# android calendar provider

Tags: android, android-calendar

well my code is:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            if(task.isEventSet()==false)    {
                Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set((int)task.getTaskYear(),(int) task.getTaskMonth(), (int)task.getTaskDay(), (int)task.getTaskHour(), (int)task.getTaskMinute());
                Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                i.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);
                i.putExtra(Events._ID, task.getId());
                i.putExtra(Events.TITLE, task.getName());
                i.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, task.getLocation());
                i.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, c.getTimeInMillis());
                task.setEventSet(true);
                context=v.getContext();
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
```

My Question is when I click on an icon the calendar application pops up where I can store my event details. Suppose if I press cancel or OK button durng the setup of an event, what is the response code returned by the calendar? I need to use this response code to set the `task.setEventSet` depending on the action performed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

You'll get a callback to `onActivityResult()` with the response code.